# Можно ли сократить кол-во запросов к БД

Tags: python, django

```
from mainapp.models import Tag
def filter_tags(tags_string):
    tags = list(map(lambda x: x.lower().strip(), tags_string.split(',')))
    done_tags = []
    for tag in tags:
        if tag:
            done_tags.append(tag)
    return done_tags


def string_to_tags(tags_string: str):
    tags = filter_tags(tags_string)  # возвращает массив строк
    tags_l = []
    for tag in tags:
        tags_l.append(Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0])  # получение существующих тегов или создание не достающих TODO: затратно

    return tags_l
```

Можно ли в string_to_tags() обойтись только одним запросом к БД создавая не достающие теги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tag.objects.bulk_create([Tag(name=tag) for tag in tags], ignore_conflicts=True)
```

Comment: Просто создавались теги, даже если такие уже были, но я допер, что нужно поле name в models.py отметить уникальным

Comment: e.tags.set(Tag.objects.bulk_create([Tag(name=tag) for tag in ['dog', 'alf']], ignore_conflicts=True)) возвращает ошибку (Cannot add "<Tag: dog>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None") наверно потому, что bulk_create() возвращает не полноценные объекты, так что данное решение не подходит, есть еще варианты?

Comment: `e.tags.set(Tag.objects.filter(name__in=tags))`